# Linux - grep function

Tags: linux, bash, grep, upgrade

i am currently making a script that searches all .mp3 files by idTags. I am using id3tools.
Main problem with my code is that it will only work when the file path will only contain 5 of "/".
I have to make it work 100% of the time, no matter what the file path is. 
My code:

```
#!/bin/bash
find /home -name \*.mp3 > songs.txt 
while read line ; do
    echo "$line" > new.txt

    filePath=`cut -d "/" -f 1,2,3,4 new.txt`
    name=` cut -d "/" -f 5 new.txt` 

    cd "$filePath"
    id3tool "$name" > tmp.txt

    if grep -q "2020" tmp.txt
    then
        echo $name
fi
    cd
done < songs.txt
```

for example file path that will work: /home/bednar/Pobrane/fileName.mp3
and on the screen will ocure fileName.mp3

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: how do i convert filePath and name to be universal.

Comment: currently it only works with the filePath that has 5 of  "/"